# Skip file when creating archive of cisco flash

Tags: cisco

I'm using the following command to create an archive of all the files on the cisco device:

```
archive tar /create tftp://192.168.1.1/everything.tar flash:
```

That normally works fine, but on devices with a file called `multiple-fs` I see:

```
%Error opening flash:/multiple-fs (Permission denied)
```

...despite being connected as a super user.

Is it possible to skip that file and archive all other files?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of -- short of list each file individually. There's no `--exclude` like GNU Tar or rsync.

Comment: Is it possible to do a dir and somehow pipe it to archive? (minus the multiple-fs file of course...)

Comment: Please check this https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/network-management/eem-copy-multiple-file-from-flash-to-ftp/td-p/1515639#3226879. TCL can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a similar issue on a really old 3550. This was a bug (this file is supposed to be readable).

Upgrade your switch